# How we can experiment with rgb here so that we get a shade of red each iteration

Tags: three.js

```
  var count = dbIds.length;
        let intensity = 0.5;
        let r=1;
        let g=0;
        let b=0;
        var red = new THREE.Vector4(r,g,b,0.5);
       dbIds.forEach(function (dbId) {

                        viewer.setThemingColor(dbId, red);  
                   
}
```

I want to set shade of red in each iteration. Any idea how we can experiment with rgb here so that we get a shade of red each iteration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change intensity by:

```
let precision = 100;
let intensity = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 * precision - 0 * precision) + 0 * precision) / (1*precision);
```